# When clearing a vector that I'm already iterating through, is it more efficient to remove elements along the way or to clear it when finished?

Tags: c++

I'm iterating through a vector, accessing each element along the way, and when I'm done the vector needs to be empty. Is it better to remove elements along the way or just to clear the entire vector when I'm done iterating?

Example 1 (iterating in reverse order because I assume that's more efficient for removing elements):

```
std::vector<int> myInts;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    myInts.push_back(i);

for (int i = myInts.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    MyFunction(myInts[i]);
    myInts.pop_back();
}
```

Example 2:

```
std::vector<int> myInts;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    myInts.push_back(i);

for (int i = 0; i < myInts.size(); ++i)
    MyFunction(myInts[i]);

myInts.clear();
```

Comment: Why not benchmark it and see?

Comment: I guess I'm hoping to learn the reasoning behind whatever result the benchmark would give me.

Comment: Most likely the second case will be faster, if there is a difference.  Only way to really know though is to benchmark it.

Comment: I would expect a tiny bit of performance edge for the first version of the code. I did not benchmark.

Comment: Also, a clever compiler could transform the first code into the second.

Comment: @BrandonLyons then benchmark it and ask questions based on the results if you don't understand them.  Also, godbolt is pretty informative for stuff like this: https://godbolt.org/z/RnBETZ

Comment: Not sure if the benchmark is correct but here is a test: http://quick-bench.com/OTxqSHIEpE2a-b7G_40QfusB0jE

Comment: @SergeyA Can you explain? Is it just because of the redundant `.size()` calls?

Comment: @BrandonLyons Probably better to benchmark _first_, then ask how to explain your results.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit without any proof whatsoever, but yes, this is my speculation.

Comment: @SergeyA: Dunno, second one's gotta read `size()` on each iteration, but first one's gotta _write_ `size()` on each iteration ;) Anyway always fun to guess hehe